# Giving Projection for more than one .png format at same time using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3, batch, png

I want to give a projection for multiple PNG files at the same time i.e. not one by one.

Is there a tool for this or can we give a projection to that folder?

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324230/give-projection-at-one-time-for-more-than-1-png-format/324248#comment528027_324230) the way to do this is by using the batch grid:

> Right click on the Define Projection tool and select 'batch' then drag
>   and drop your PNG files from ArcCatalog or Explorer into the tool,
>   define the CRS you want to give in the first row then right click and
>   select 'fill' and all others will be populated.

For more information see the Online Help page titled [A quick tour of batch processing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/a-quick-tour-of-batch-processing.htm).